# What is the definition of the duality group $E_{7(7)}$?

Tags: string-theory, group-theory, lie-algebra, supergravity

1. What is the definition of the duality group $E_{7(7)}$ that appears in [${\cal N}=8$ Supergravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%3D8_Supergravity) and what are the basics properties?
2. Moreover what is the relation with the Lie Algebra $E_7$?
3. Please, provide some reference in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wikipedia explains, [$E_7$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E7_%28mathematics%29) refers to several, closely related real and complex [Lie groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) and [Lie algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra).

All the various $E_7$ Lie groups (algebras) are Lie subgroups (subalgebras) of the complex Lie group $E_7$ (algebra $e_7$), respectively. The latter has complex dimension $133$ and [rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_subgroup) $7$.

Specifically, $E_{7(7)}\equiv E_{7(+7)}\equiv E_{7,7}$ is a real Lie group, where the corresponding Lie algebra is a [split Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_Lie_algebra), and its [Killing form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form) is a split real form. The $E_{7,7}$ Lie group is a subgroup of $Sp(56;\mathbb{R})$.

For the actual group constructions, see e.g. [arXiv:1007.4758](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4758).

The non-compact Lie group $E_{7,7}$ is the duality group of [${\cal N}=8$ supergravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%3D8_Supergravity) in $D=4$. The discrete [$U$-duality group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-duality) of type II string theory compactified on a six-torus $T^6$ is $$E_{7,7}(\mathbb{Z}):=E_{7,7} \cap Sp(56;\mathbb{Z}),$$
as originally conjectured in [arXiv:hep-th/9410167](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9410167).